# In $readmemh command, how to specify to read from a starting address to ending address

Tags: image-processing, matrix, slice, verilog, system-verilog

I have a 360x640 matrix i.e. 230,400 pixel values. Using `$readmemh`, I want to read only a specific part of matrix and store it in matrix `Y_luma` (read only the 8x8 matrix values inside the square box i.e. from 154 to 148 and store it in first row of matrix `Y_luma`, from 152 to 153 store in 2nd row of matrix `Y_luma` and so on until 155 to 152 in 8th row of `Y_luma`).

[image]

The code I tried is:

```
module matrix_copy;

    reg [7:0] Y_luma [0:7][0:7];
    
    $readmemh("Luma_space.txt", Y_luma,
```

Not able to proceed afterwards. How to specify the start address i.e. [8][8] and stop address i.e. [8][15] in first row of matrix `Y_luma` and also, how to store the next array from [9][8] to [9][15] in 2nd row of matrix `Y_luma` and so on?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to declare another memory variable which exactly matches the size of the input file and read the entire file into that memory (addresses 0 to 230,399).  Then you can use `for` loops to selectively load your `Y_luma` variable.

```
reg [7:0] mem [360*640];
initial $readmemh("Luma_space.txt", mem);
```

This avoids any error or warning messages about incorrect memory size.

Also refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.4.3 *File format considerations for multidimensional unpacked arrays*.  However, it might require that your input file be in a very specific format, perhaps with address entries (`@0`).

`$readmemh` does have optional `start_addr` and `finish_addr` arguments, but  it might be tricky getting them to work with your configuration.

Here is [one example of the optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72193511/197758).

Comment: The post does not say if this is simulation only or RTL for synthesis.  If this is for synthesis a large ROM will be created using LUTS for the big table.  The parts have a lot of LUTS so the utilization should not be an issue, however if the part is running fast this may produce timing closure issues because a big ROM will have many levels of logic.

Comment: @Mikef yes in the end i have to synthesize the code in cadence. But initially i am experimenting it on xilinx, but having issue in xilinx.                                                                 module matrix_read;
reg [7:0] Y_luma [0:230399];
initial $readmemh("dummy.txt", Y_luma);
reg [7:0] store [0:50];
generate
 for(genvar k=0; k<50; k=k+1)
  assign store [k]= Y_luma [k]; 
endgenerate
initial begin
#10;
$display("%d",Y_luma);
$display("%d",store);
end
endmodule    Even this simple code is unable to run, shows exceeds maximum traceable size and ISim shows fatal error